# How do I redirect a request for an IP to the loopback?

Tags: redirection, tcp

A program I'm using makes a request for the external IP 74.125.234.83 and I would like to make this request redirect to 127.0.0.1 so I can test my local server, I don't have access to the source of the program so I have to make that request redirect to the loopback on the operating system.

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate, how can I do that ?

Comment: Is the program resolving that address or is 74... hardcoded? If it's resolving it, just create an entry in the hosts file to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: The program does not resolve, it connects directly to that address :(

Comment: Fire up a hex editor and replace the string/address in the binary :P

Comment: That's a possibility but I was wondering if there was a way to do that using the OS :)

Comment: You should probably move this question to superuser or serverfault - the solution you are looking for is really not a development question.

Comment: I agree, should I create a new question there or there's a way to move the question itself?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46240/how-to-move-a-question-from-superuser-to-stackoverflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add that hardcoded IP to the loop back interface and set the netmask to 255.255.255.255 (/32).

You can't do that through a GUI, so you'll have to use the `netsh` command. Use `netsh int ip sh int` to get the interface id of the loop back interface and `netsh int ip add addr <ID> <IP>/32 st=ac sk=tr` to add the address. (Help can be found by typing `netsh int ip add addr` with no arguments.)

This will affect all programs on your computer though.

Answer (score 0):

Your keywords is "Destination NAT" (DNAT).

I never tried to configure NAT in windows, but I think is possible to configure NAT:

- http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/using-windows-server-nat-router.html
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457077.aspx